# Refused to execute script from 'file_name.php' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, header

I make a site. It's working properly on my local server but when I upload it to live server it is giving me this error:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://www.mahijat.tk/new/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/autoptimize_c648c3203309d095775637e672c00239.php' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

My site URL is http://www.mahijat.tk/new/

My `index.php` file code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js ">
```

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:image" content="../pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/601407094277873664/WT2mk28E_400x400.jpg" />
<link type="text/css" media="all" href="wp-content/cache/autoptimize/autoptimize_ac4e9617d860b901a683f7676a3c44be.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" media="all" href="wp-content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: is there even any PHP in this file?

Comment: not sir there is only html ,javascript, and jquery code

Comment: What is the nature of the code being called in 'http://www.mahijat.tk/new/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/autoptimize_c648c3203309d095775637e672c00239.php? Where is it being called if someone visits your website?

Comment: @TidyDev it was just a javascript code for i user animation in my site

Comment: @TidyDev now I checked my site in firefox i working perfectly but in chrome it is throwing error

Comment: By default Autoptimize uses "text/javascript" for JS-files served via PHP (non-static). If you get "text/html" something (a .htaccess rule?) is somehow overwriting the content-type HTTP response header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually a Chrome error that happens when you make an AJAX `jsonp` request to a page that returns javascript but incorrectly sends a `Content-Type: text/html` header.

You can fix it by changing your `autoptimize_.....php` file to send the proper Content-Type header before outputting the javascript:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
// rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go and refer the [link](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/180)

Hope this might help you.

Try to do a hard refresh (CMD + SHIFT + R).

Comment: i try this and i clear all the browser cache but didn't work